# Volley json parameter

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have two textviews set in onCreate as follows;

```
tv1.setText("john");
tv2.setText("smithh");
```

why does this work:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
    parameters.put("param1", "John");
    parameters.put("param2", "Smith");
    return parameters;
}
```

but not this:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String myID1 = tv1.getText().toString();
    String myID2 = tv2.getText().toString();
    parameters.put("param1", myID1);
    parameters.put("param2", myID2);
    return parameters;
}
```

and how do I get around this issue please so I can postmy  variables to my PHP code that creates the Json?

Comment: I think that tv1.getText() and tv2.getText() have NULL. did you debug them?

Comment: I have them displayed on the xml so they are not null. For some reason it works if I use EditText but not TextView??

Comment: post full code with xml

Comment: There are no reasons If they have value. Can I see your more code?

Comment: I have solved it, there was a space at the end of tv1.setText("john "); How embarrasing